# How to extend a given function to an odd function with period 2 (Fourier Series)

Tags: functions, fourier-series

This is the question.

```
f(x) = 7x^2 + 4
```

I want to know how to extend the above fuction to become a odd function with period 2.

Comment: Please can you let me know why my question is voted down so I can improve my way of asking questions?

Comment: @isuru-buddihika, usually you have to provide some evidence that you've tried to solve the problem before asking. Like, some progress or general thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x) = f(x), 0\leq x\leq 1,$

$g(x) = -f(x), -1 \leq x \leq 0,$

$ g(x) = g(x+2)$ to define g(x) in x $\in \mathbb R$

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought of different ways but couldn't figure this out.